# Receive files in Java bean in XPages

Tags: java, rest, xpages, lotus-domino

I am creating service that can receive files and attach them to document.

I have created HTML form that is used to submit files (example below).

**TEST FORM**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Test-form to upload files (v.1.0.0) </h1>

    <form action="/file.xsp/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <p>
        Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
       </p>

       <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Once form is submitted Java bean is triggered and below is example.

**JAVA BEAN**

```
public class TestFile extends CustomServiceBean {

    @Override
    public void renderService(CustomService service, RestServiceEngine engine) throws ServiceException {
        print ("START: Uploading of file...");

        HttpServletResponse res = engine.getHttpResponse();
        HttpServletRequest req = engine.getHttpRequest();

        ...
```

However I do not know how to initialize InputStream to file that is submitted to service. Can anybody suggest (or example) how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: In my fileVault project I have an example of getting a file via an XAgent I believe.  I then use Java code to manipulate it.  https://bitbucket.org/leedy/filevault  I also did a more basic example on my NotesIn9 screencast.  http://www.notesin9.com/2016/08/25/notesin9-194-upload-files-with-plupload/   Maybe that will help.

Comment: @David : don't be so modest to comment only. Your entry warrants to be an acceptable reply

Comment: @DavidLeedy, thanks for comment. I could not find a java bean there, would you please help me to find it if it is there?

Comment: Stephan - Thanks.  Since all I had are links to examples and I wasn't pasting details I always thought StackOverFlow didn't like that...

Comment: Dmytro - You don't really upload direct to a "bean".  You can upload to an XAgent or Servlet.  The video I linked to shows uploading to an XAgent.  I might be using SSJS there rather then Java I forget.  It could certainly be converted to Java. But the video should show you the procedure.

Comment: @DavidLeedy - understood. Thanks. Going to re-view video again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it applies to submit a file to a bean, but I used something similar to the following code to validate uploaded file properties like size.

In my case the POST was made by an XPage which is probably not your case so maybe it won't apply.

```
HttpServletRequest request= engine.getHttpRequest();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String,Object> params=request.getParameterMap();

for (Entry<String, Object> tmpEntry : params.entrySet()) {
    if (tmpEntry.getValue() instanceof UploadedFile) {
        UploadedFile myFile=(UploadedFile)tmpEntry.getValue();
        //Do something with the file
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked well for me.
I could not receive file handler because files have been already posted on Domino and therefore request body was empty.
I did not know that :).

Comment: Good to know this will work with non XPages html web pages. ;-)